# How do you downgrade php8.0 to php7.4 in Ubuntu 21.10

Tags: php7, 21.10

Normally you would use add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php, however, there does not seem to be a release file for 21.10 so it does not add the repository. A few websites I have setup do not work with php8.0 so I am trying to find out how to downgrade to php7.4, but the instructions for 21.04 do not work for 21.10. Is there another way to do this outside of using ondrej/php repo?

Comment: I am looking for the same. Maybe is time to back to 21.04 :)